# Javascript : update input value via ajax on modal shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.1

I have a modal which I show it on an element click.
So I want to update an input value in this modal via Ajax, I can retrieve data successfully but it doesn't update its value normally (get a value of an other article record not the current articleID), here my code :

```
$('#editArticle').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    ...
    $articleID =  $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",                
            url : 'article/'+ $articleID +'/getData',                
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data){                    
                document.getElementById("serial").value = data['serial'];
            }
    });  
});
```

and if I set alert to show data it returns the right value :

```
success : function(data){ 
                alert(data['serial']); // here it returns the right value for each row, and it appears after the modal show !!!!                   
                document.getElementById("serial").value = data['serial'];
            }
```

Records are listed in datatable : 
[image]
 What's the mistake ?!

Comment: Why you are not using click event listener?

Comment: Can you post what is in `data`? Also whats the purpose in using jquery and then reverting to JS for the `document.getElementById`? Why not use jQuery selector?: `$("#serial").val(data['serial']);`

Comment: @FernandoUrban I click on link as this :
<a data-toggle='modal'  data-target='#editArticle' data-id="{{ $article->id }}" role='button' href='#'>

Comment: @Noctane data is an array (laravel 5 eloquent)

Comment: I don't know what laravel is but I usually access objects in the response with a dot, like `data.serial` in your case, if you put a break point on that line inside the success and put a watch on `data['serial']` what is it's value?

Comment: First question, what are you `POST`ing? And if just the `csrf-token`, why not use `GET`? Do you get any errors in your Network tab? (`F12` in Firefox and Chrome.) Also, is the `url` you're `POST`ing to correct?

Comment: @Noctane I set alert(data['serial']) it returns the right value !

Comment: @TimLewis I've just tried Get but the same problem :/
I edited my question for more details

Comment: @BKF this `get a value of an other article record not the current articleID` happens when modal open very first time too or does it show the correct `articleID` first time and then problem occurs from 2nd attempt to open modal with different record?

Comment: @Shehary yes exactly and it keeps the first value !

Comment: @BKF change event from `show` to `shown` `$('#editArticle').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {}` to `$('#editArticle').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {}` see if it fixes the issue

Comment: The same but I saw that the alert message appears after modal shown !! any idea ?

Comment: @BKF. other possibilities, check  if  id `serial` is unique, throughout the page or there may b typo or change it to something different and check.

Comment: How many elements with the id serial do you have? console.log($('#serial').length);

Comment: @Shehary it's unique

Comment: @manuerumx $('#serial').length = 1

Comment: Can you prepare a demo using jsfiddle or codebin that duplicates the issue, so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, try to clone the modal first then find the id or class in cloned modal.
In this example, i'm using a bootstrap dialog as plugin.
Please, take a look :

```js
var modal = $('.modal').clone();

BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'blabla',
    message: modal.show(),
    onshow: function() {
      $(modal).find('#result').text('updated text');
    },
    buttons: [{
      label: 'Cancel',
      action: function(dialogRef) {
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    }]
});
```

```html
<div class="modal" style="display:none">
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this code works for your problem